# React-Router V4 - Passing Props to Render function in Route Component to generate new component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router-v4

I can't get my head around how to render a child component of `<Route>` that will check a prop boolean from a parent to see if the state is authorized. I want to be able to pass other props using spread to future proof it. Could someone help me to try and unscrew this?

Here is my code for the Private Route I am trying to create:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { app } from '../Base'



export const PrivateRoute = (props) => (
  <Route {...props} render={(props.authenticated) => (
    {props.authenticated} === true
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/' />
  )}/>
)
```

And my App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      authenticated: false,
      loading: true
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
        this.removeAuthListener = app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
            this.setState({
              authenticated: true,
              loading: false
            })
          } else {
            this.setState({
              authenticated: false,
              loading: false
            })
          }
        })
  }




  componentWillUnmount () {
      this.removeAuthListener();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading === true){
      return (
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center", position: "absolute", top: "25%", left: "50%"}}>
        <h3>Loading</h3>
      </div>
    )} else{
    return (
      <div style= { sectionStyle } className="App">
        <div className="Jumbotron">
            <Header authenticated={this.state.authenticated}/>
            <Switch> 
                <Route exact path="/" render={() => {

                }}component={Jumbo}/>
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout}/>
                <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} authenticated={this.state.authenticated}/>
                <Route component={NotFound}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

In the inline function you pass to `render`, you have access to `props` so you could do something like this:

```
export const PrivateRoute = (props) => (
  <Route to={props.path} render={() => {
    if(props.authenticated) {
        return <Component {...props} />;
    }

    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }}/>
);
```

Comment: thanks for checking out my problem. I am having some issues with compiling. When I try out the above script I receive instance.render is not a function.

Comment: I had missed a closing `}` - not sure if that was the problem though

Comment: No it wasn't that. I am looking into adding a private route using children. I am going to add my app.js code above too if you could take a look if thats the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I think this should be written like

```
export const PrivateRoute = (props) => (
  <Route {...props} render={({...props}) => (
    {props.authenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/' />
  }/>
)
```

And make sure `authenticate` is well passed through your top component.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      (Meteor.userId() ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: '/',
            state: { from: props.location },
          }}
        />
      ))
    }
  />
);

export const renderRoutes = () => (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={props => <Dashboard {...props} data={{ main: Promotions }} />} />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/coin/:coin/:address" component={props => <Dashboard {...props} data={{ main: Wallet }} />} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```